# Autocomplete for repeating text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

Good day! I have a form that enables a user to dynamically add and remove input text fields.
Each text field should suggest some values or autocomplete. Adding and removing fields are successful. However, only the first text field autosuggests.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>

$(function() {
    var availableTags = @Html(Json.toJson(tagNames).toString); 

    var scntDiv = $('#addMore');
    var i = $('#addMore p').size() + 1;



    $('#addRT').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="tags"><input id="tags" type="text" name="relatedTags.tag.name" placeholder="Name"/></label> <a href="#" id="remRT">Remove</a></p>', 
                    function() {
                        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                            source: availableTags
                        });
                    }).appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;

            return false;
    });

    $('#remRT').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 1 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });

});

$(function() {
    var availableTags = @Html(Json.toJson(tagNames).toString); 
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});


</script>
```

But the same problem persists. Please help me figure this out. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are adding multiple elements with the same ID, no good. Add a dynamic ID (via an increment variable) or use a class instead.

Comment: Thank you but I am using `java.util.Map<String, String[]> map = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();` in the controller so having a same ID is not a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been precise enough: Your JavaScript function that adds a new input, always add an input with the ID 'tags'. Then you apply your autocomplete plugin to the (one!) element with the ID 'tags'. As IDs are meant to be unique, $('#tags') only returns 1 element. That's why only 1 field works.

Comment: Same is true for your remove link, you should rather use a class `.remRT` instead of an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comments, this should solve at least your autocomplete function. The ID is dynamically created by using the iterator you already had in your code.

```
$('#addRT').live('click', function() {
        $('<p><label for="tags"><input id="tags'+i+'" type="text" name="relatedTags.tag.name" placeholder="Name"/></label> <a href="#" id="remRT">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);

        $( "#tags"+i ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });

        i++;

        return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you but autocomplete still only happens in the first text field. I also tried moving the function out of the `$(")` and declared another variable as `i` but it's still the same.

Comment: I just changed the code example above. Looking at the Jquery docs, doing $('html', function) is nowhere to be found, I think this was never called, thus never actually invoked. Moving it to after adding the new input should properly attach it.